# How get the "real" user ip address?

Tags: django, geoip

i tried to get the "real" user ip address, it's working, but i'm not getting my own ip (the real one), checking the ip with google map, after convert it to long - lat, google map is showing the location of my ISP.

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

What i want to do, is display a map from the exact location from the user sent a article.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method available server side is IP, which will always resolve to your ISP.

The more advanced methods present a security risk, so the user gets prompted to allow them (thus only available client side).  Take a look at HTML5 GEO for more info:

http://html5demos.com/geo

http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get anything more precise than this. The IP address being reported is the right one, but IP address location is dependent on the ISP. For a desktop computer, that's as good as it gets.

The IP you are currently retrieving is the one that is received by your application, for all the web app know, that's you, but you could be behind a proxy or a VPN, and the app would never know.